# Ask jQuery to perform X time an action

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I have a `<div id="sliderButtons"></div>`
and i have a `var NumberOfSlide`

what i want is to `append` on my div :  `NumberOfSlide`* `<span>button</span>`

i don't know how to ask jQuery to append `NumberOfSlide` time

**Exemple**

if `var NumberOfSlide = 3;`

the result would be :

```
<div id="sliderButtons">
   <span>button</span>
   <span>button</span>
   <span>button</span>
</div>
```

I hope i made it clear enough for you to help me !

Comment: A [simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FStatements#Loop_Statements) would solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var contents = (new Array(NumberOfSlide + 1)).join("<span>button</span>");
$('#sliderButtons').append(contents);
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zHbVB/

PS: what is good in this particular solution in comparison to the others (as they are at this moment) is that you create a string and then modify your DOM just once with `.append()`. Whereas other solutions (except of  [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)'s [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18868757/251311)) propose you to perform `.append()` multiple times, which generally considered as a bad idea.

Comment: well, not all the other solutions ?

Comment: +1 btw, I always forget about using the join() method like that.

Comment: @adeneo: +1 as well, I haven't seen `.append()` accepts a function reference

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#sliderButtons').append(function() {
    var html = $([]);
    for (var i=0; i<NumberOfSlide; i++) {
        html = html.add( $('<span />', {text : 'button'}) );
    }
    return html;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nd8NE/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery to do the loop, but you can use it for the appending:

```
for(var i=0; i< NumberOfSlide; i++) {
  $("#sliderButtons").append($("<span>").text("button"));
}
```